# Get call/video chat length and members

Tags: slack-api, phone-call, duration, membership

Is there a way to get the length of a slack call from the API?  In the app, I can see a call lasted 15 minutes but the API response for calls does not seem to include a time length.  We are using the conversations.history endpoint with a user oauth token.  We've tried pulling a call up both from a larger list or asking for the call's conversation message by it's timestamp value.  Here is an example of a phone call as returned by the Slack API:

```
0 => JoliCode\Slack\Api\Model\ObjsMessage^ {#2054
      #attachments: null
      #blocks: null
      #botId: null
      #clientMsgId: null
      #comment: null
      #displayAsBot: null
      #file: null
      #files: null
      #icons: null
      #inviter: null
      #isDelayedMessage: null
      #isIntro: null
      #isStarred: null
      #lastRead: null
      #latestReply: null
      #name: null
      #oldName: null
      #parentUserId: null
      #permalink: "https://<snip>.slack.com/call/<snip>"
      #pinnedTo: null
      #purpose: null
      #reactions: null
      #replies: null
      #replyCount: null
      #replyUsers: null
      #replyUsersCount: null
      #sourceTeam: null
      #subscribed: null
      #subtype: "sh_room_created"
      #team: null
      #text: "Started a <https://<snip>.slack.com/call/<snip>|call>."
      #threadTs: null
      #topic: null
      #ts: "1589834349.006000"
      #type: "message"
      #unreadCount: null
      #upload: null
      #user: "<snip>"
      #userProfile: null
      #userTeam: null
      #username: null
    }
```